# Vertical ListView display

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

Im tryingh to create a list view but im having issues designing it how I want it, I know about Windows Presentation foundation (WPF) but as im studying C# and the language itself im tackling it from the more difficult prospective.

I would assume that `View.List` would be the way to go with a small tinker with `OwnerDraw` and `OnDraw` but i still seem to be having issues

What im building in a Youtube Browser and the desired layout would be like so:

```
---------------------------------------------
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- | I | | Some Title here                   -
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- | I | | Some Title here                   -
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- | I | | Some Title here                   -
- ----- ----------------------------------- -
- ----------------------------------------- -
```

Looking at the above layout you can see that I need that so there's 1 row per line, which is my main issue I cant get around, the `I` would be an image, and the text to the right would.

Can anyone help me figure out what settings or code i would need to make to get this sorting, its really blocking progress :(

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest one of two things

1- Use a ListBox and owner draw that

2- Use a ListView in Detail view and then owner draw the items as you describe above.

Comment: The problem im having is making sure the ListViewitem is 1 per line in OwnerDraw Call

Comment: @RobertPitt, I might be missing something, but if you have the ListView is in Detail view then there is one ListViewItem per line.